# MySQL - [1045] SQLSTATE Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, localhost

Saw many questions similar but still not able to find the clue.

My new Symfony2 project uses this kind of config

```
[parameters]
    database_driver   = pdo_mysql
    database_host     = localhost
    database_port     =
    database_name     = my_db
    database_user     = my_user
    database_password = my_password
```

I'm able to connect with the command line client

```
$ mysql -u my_user -p
Enter password:
mysql>
```

But trying to populate my database

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

Gives me

> Could not create database for connection named my_db
>   SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my_password contained the character `@` or `&` which apparently prevented me to connect with PDO